# Angular 2 routes children with outlets

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

Currently trying to learn about Angular 2 routing and I've come across an issue that I cannot resolve, it feels like it is some sort of syntax or config that I am simply missing.

I want to have two router outlets on the one page and be able to show two separate sections on the page that a user can individually navigate.

I tried following the code from here - http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

However when I do this I get an error saying it cannot find the route that the child routes are on.

Here's the code:

Routes

```
{
    path: 'full',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'list',
            component: ListComponent,
            outlet: 'list'
        }
    ]
}
```

In the full component:

```
<div divOne>
    <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div divTwo>
    <router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And I navigate like this:

```
    let navigationExtras: any = {
        queryParams: { reference: 21 },
        outlets: {'list': ['list']}
    };

    this.router.navigate( ['full'], navigationExtras);
```

This gives me the following error message:

> core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'full'

If I take the outlet out of the child route I dont get this error message.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The component needs exactly one unnamed router-outlet and can have additional named outlets

```ts
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="full"></router-outlet>

this.router.navigate( ['full'], navigationExtras);
```

navigate([{outlets: {route3: 'productPage'}}]);

```ts
  navigate() {
    let navigationExtras: any = {
      queryParams: { reference: 21 },
      outlets: {full: 'full']}
    };
    this.router.navigate([navigationExtras]);
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BoX4gRVKF4tczR3fOeTX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

First argument of `router.navigate` method should be `['/full']` instead of `['full']`.

`this.router.navigate(['/full'], navigationExtras);`